# Rsync transfer via SSH is very slow

Tags: backup, rsync

I am making a remote backup of my website. Whole catalog is about 70GB with about 5,000,000 of files total. Here is the command that I run on my backup server:

```
rsync -ah -e ssh --delete --link-dest=/backups/2013.09.06 backuper@88.245.49.132:/var/www/backups/2013.09.07
```

Process runs more than 48 hours and just hangs.

I've ran `strace -p` of rsync process on client (webserver where website is located) and saw, that process periodicly stops at `select` command ending with `= 0 (Timeout)` after some time, then continues.

```
open("mysite/files/1694201", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10083, ...}) = 0
read(3, "\r\n\320\224\320\265\321\201\321\217\321\202\321\214 \320\273\320\265\321\202, \321\210\320\265\321\201\321\202\321"..., 10083) = 10083
select(2, NULL, [1], [1], {60, 0})      = 1 (out [1], left {59, 999998})
write(1, "\374\17\0\7", 4)              = 4
select(2, NULL, [1], [1], {60, 0})      = 1 (out [1], left {59, 999999})
write(1, "\320\260\320\262\320\260\320\271\321\202\320\265...\320\232\320\270\320\264\320\260\320\271\321\202\320\265 \320\274"..., 4092) = 4092
select(2, NULL, [1], [1], {60, 0})      = 1 (out [1], left {59, 999999})
write(1, "\374\17\0\7", 4)              = 4
select(2, NULL, [1], [1], {60, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
```

Process hangs on the last line for a minute or so.

Why can this be happening? Why the process takes so long and never reaches the end? What could those `0 (Timeout)` in strace mean?

Both servers run rsync 3.0.9, IO is not overloaded.

Comment: If not IO, what about the network ? What kind of internet connection do you have ? 70GB through a normal DSL line can be very long.

Comment: @Kwaio Speed between serves is about 3 MB/sec. But `select()` is a local operation, is it not?

Comment: Nope, select applies on a file descriptor, which can be a network socket. Speed seems high enough, but there may be temporar overloads on the network. Try to run a continuous ping or mtr during this time and look for lag spikes correlating with timeouts.

Comment: Have a look at kernel's open file descriptors too, that could be a culprit.

Answer (score 1):

> What could those 0 (Timeout) in strace mean?

Go read up on the 5th parameter [passed to select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Plainly rsync (on its own) is not appropriate for the method you have chosen for backing up the files. It has to generate a hash for each of 5 million files and send that across the network just to find if anything has changed.

If it were me, I'd wrap it up in a script running on the source server which

1. Checks the time (tstart) the previous successful sync was started
2. Finds all files on the source which have a mtime > tstart
3. rsync those files modified to the backup server

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch newrun
find /var/www -newer lastrun -exec rsync ....
rm -f lastrun
mv newrun lastrun
```

Comment: rsync per default actually does check for changes in modification timestamp or size. The checksum is only calculated when needed (or requested via the option --checksum).

Comment: Yes - and then it COMPARES the timestamps with the reference set (i.e. across the network)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have 5 billion files?

I'd rather tgz and rsync that tgz, since the initial comparison from src to dst would take
forever if you have somewhat "normal" hds, no high-speed SAN or SSD.

where does your process is slow? during file-transfer or during initial src<->dst - check?(sending incremental file list ...)

I'd check IOWAIT on both ends, if possible. and, if machines have md-raid, cat /proc/mdstatus. very bad io-performance can be a result of a rebuilding raid (but very unlikely).

and i'd to a transfer with a single large file with `--progress` switched on during rsync-transfer to check network-speed.

**debugging hints** (you should test each possible bottleneck, even just to make sure: this is NOT the problem)

- try rsync with -avzh --progress --stats
- io-performance locally
- network-performance
- hd/raid-status (SMART), check for faulty hardware

Comment: Hum. that would rather cancel the intrest of rsync doing incremental backups... even if i have to admit that 5billion files is toomuch. Maybe it would be a better advice to split the backup in several sub-folders to have less files per process ?

Comment: (I'm not the one asking the question) I was just suggesting to split the task between several `rsync`process to limit the file tree comparison part time. and the per-process open file descriptors

Comment: rsync can become very slow (not the transfer itself) with millions of files, because rsync intially checks the filelist src<->dst to decide which files/part of files to transfer. this can take a loooooong time if you have slow disks and manymanymany files. another fs like xfs might help a little.

Comment: oh, sorry, 3 extra zeroes! *5 million* files, not *billion*

Comment: @Temnovit: how long does `find ./ -type f | wc -l ` takes? what is your IOWAIT - value for that time? (you can check this with top or vmstat/iostat. still tyring to find out if this might be an os/fs - problem. what happens if you run this rsync with a local dst?

Comment: see my debugging-hints